# ¿Es válido hacer roll-back de ediciones?

Tags: discusión

Editando una pregunta quise volver a verla y me la encontré sin cambios, al parecer alguien más la editó para que quedara sin modificaciones.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/73/revisions

[image: pantallazo]

¿Es esta una buena práctica?

Comment: No creo que sea buena práctica si no se indica el porqué. Probablemente podrías consultar a la persona que lo hizo citándola con `@Carlos Muñoz`. Al mencionarlo así será avisado, podréis debatirlo y estoy seguro que llegar a alguna conclusión útil para todos.

Comment: Por cierto nunca me notificó, creo que es sin espacios: @CarlosMuñoz

Comment: claro que es valido, para eso lo pusieron allí. y algo mas _no debes cambiar la intención del autor_

Comment: ¿Y cómo se cambia la _intención del autor_? ¿Autor de qué?O.o

Answer (score 9):

En primer lugar (hasta donde yo sé) al hacer *rollback* **no hay forma de mencionar un motivo**, de lo contrario hubiera indicado de forma resumida lo que expongo a continuación

La razón por la que hice el rollback es que ese código adicional no lo editó el autor original [**@mattias**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/71/mattias) sino que fue una edición posterior que agregaba código que el autor original **nunca incluyó en su respuesta** ni en los comentarios.

Este código adicional cambia la respuesta ya que así como estaba originalmente sin comentarios obtuvo votos negativos y la respuesta actual probablemente hubiera obtenido votos positivos.

Por otro lado entiendo que es posible que esta edición pueda ser entendida como un intento de mejora de la respuesta, sin embargo a mi parecer no aporta nada nuevo ya que la solución es la misma de otras respuestas que ya existían: la [respuesta de I.G. Pascual](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-saber-si-un-elemento-est%C3%A1-visible-con-jquery/210#210) y la [mía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-saber-si-un-elemento-est%C3%A1-visible-con-jquery/38#38)

En mi opinión lo mejor hubiera sido publicarlo como una nueva respuesta o simplemente no editar nada.

Sin embargo si opinan diferente puedo volver a hacer rollback de nuevo y dejarlo en la revisión 2 que contiene la edición.

Comment: Me parece válido el _rollback_ por el motivo que mencionas, editar código del autor por mas mal que esté cambia la pregunta y la intención del mismo y puede generar respuestas que no atacan el problema principal u original. Es mi opinión obvio.

Comment: Buen punto. Tal vez habría sido bueno dejar un comentario sobre el rollback bajo la pregunta "he hecho rollback porque blabla..." y así sería más obvio para quien hizo la edición. Nótese que podrías haberlo mencionado con `@Ruslan...`.

Comment: @fedorqui lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima vez :)